# Keeping parent nav background active when on child page - CSS

Tags: css, nav

This seems like a fairly straightforward thing but can't find any tutorial on it.

I have a top menu that changes background colour then one of the menu items is selected. The CSS looks like this:

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a.selected {
    background-color: #F7A379;
}
```

However some pages have a side menu, with a class .left-nav and when I click on those links the background styling disappears from the parent nav. Is it possible to keep the styling above when the child page is selected? If so, what would the CSS need to be?

Comment: use `.nav > li > a.active {........ }`